# How to write the jsDoc for the reducer in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, jsdoc, reducers

I have the reducer for our component, we are following jsDoc for the documentation.But in reducer how can I cover the Switch case of reducer in document.My code and comment right now is like this:-

```
// first import the constant
import {
  REQUEST_DATA,
  RECEIVE_DATA,
} from '../constants/dataType';

// define the initial state for the reducer
const initialState = {
  dataList: [],
  loadingData: false,
};

/**
 * It will receive all the data use for the device
 * @function :  dataReducer
 * @param {object} state:contain initial and final state of data
 * @param {object} action:return the action object
 */
function dataReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    /**
    * Action Creator - requestData
    * This action is use to call the service to get the device info list
    */
    case REQUEST_DATA:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        loadingData: action.loadingData,
              });
    /**
    * Action Creator - receiveData
    * it will receive the data dispatching from the requestDevice
    */
    case RECEIVE_DATA:
     return Object.assign({}, state, {
          dataList: action.dataList,
          loadingDevice: action.loadingData,
        });
      }
      default:
      return state;
  }
}
export default dataReducer;
```

Now if we will go to the document that generated from jsdoc , It will only show the dataReducer whatever we wrote above function declaration, but what about the switch cases, I think we should cover this part also in documenation.**How we can cover the switch case of the reducer in jsDoc?**

Comment: If you use the strategy pattern to split out the different behaviours into functions - then you can document each behaviour (function)

Comment: @CallumLinington we cant split out only for document, we have to maintain the code quality and execution time also.For reducer in reactjs Switch case is optimal.In this code only we have to find the way for documentation.

Comment: Really... I highly doubt using functions is going to affect perf